# Runtime Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, runtime-error, android-constraintlayout

I created an Android application that uses Androidx.
I'm trying to run my Android app, but I get this **runtime error** when it tries to start Login Activity:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sportincenterapp, PID: 7414
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sportincenterapp/com.example.sportincenterapp.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
    at com.example.sportincenterapp.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.kt:9)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 485935644 byte allocation with 3293900 free bytes and 379MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:854)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4175)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:574)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:570)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:567)
```

**activity_login.xml** contains a simple **ConstraintLayout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/login_background"
  android:padding="20dp"
  tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_small"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etUserName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_login_background"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="  Email"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_login_background"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="   Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etUserName" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the dependencies in **build.gradle** are up-to date:

```
dependencies {

  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
  implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

and finally **LoginActivity.kt**:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I just updated the full stacktrace

Comment: Looks like your `drawable/login_background` is way too large and you run out of memory.  Try making it smaller in its dimensions

Comment: @laalto Thanks! That was the problem. The solution was in the stacktrace..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe youy try. to use vector drawable on low api device -  than you need to add this to build.gradle to support vector drawable. It should solve your problem

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
      vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
   }
}
```

Or maybe your drawable is too big